# Laravel Sanctum CSRF Cookie Request Optional

Tags: laravel, cookies, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to use Laravel Sanctum for my SPA. There are some basic home pages from web.php routes but other `axios` API interactions with the SPA are in api.php routes guarded by `auth:sanctum`

From the official documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating), it says we have to send a request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` to initialize CSRF protection prior login. However, I noticed that even without login, Laravel by default already initialized `XSRF-TOKEN` and `<app_name>_session` cookies to my browser. I do not need to initialize it via `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` and my subsequent API request in the logged-in SPA still works. Later I checked https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token and it says it is the default behavior that Laravel will include the CSRF token in each response.

My question is, is it true that `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` initialization is optional and it is safe for `axios` to use the default CSRF token return by Laravel? Or am I doing something wrong which exposes my SPA to CSRF attack?

Answer (score 4):

Your main SPA home page is probably provided by a route that is defined in your `web.php` route file as you mentionned. In `App/Http/Kernel.php`, check in your middleware groups if there is `VerifyCsrfToken::class` defined as a middleware for `web` :

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
            StartSession::class,
            ...
            VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            ...
        ]
    ]
```

This middleware is responsible for creating header response like : `set-cookie   XSRF-TOKEN=kgXZBZ4AccC0H17KEMw....` when you request any route available in `web.php` (if the cookie yet doesn't exist obviously), that will indeed initialize a `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie.

Therefore, you don't need to request route `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` when you already use this `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

However, if you are doing full SPA totally separated from your Laravel backend and deliver a html page differently, you won't have this `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie generated by default. Thus, as mentionned in Sanctum documentation, you need to request `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` to generate cookie before going further.