# Should we make a request to /sanctum/csrf-cookie first, before registration that logs in a user after a successful registration?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

My SPA is in the same repository as my laravel application and the documentation states that when using sanctum, your SPA's "login" page should first make a request to the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` endpoint to initialize CSRF protection for the application.
Link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating

In my case, When I register a user successfully I'm not redirecting them to the login page to log in but rather to their dashboard. So, in my understanding going by the point above, I think I should first make a request to the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` endpoint as well before making a `post` request to the `register api` so that we have a logged-in user that is protected from CSRF attacks but I'm not that sure if I'm interpreting the text correctly.

my method

```
public function register(Request $request){
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email', 
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);

    $fields['password'] = bcrypt($fields['password']);
    $user = User::create($fields);
    auth()->login($user);
}
```

Comment: Refer to this answer, I think it will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64695186/8485567

Comment: @BernardWiesner It didn't answer my question but I've learned something that I find very important to me. Thanks.

Comment: What part is still unclear to you? Basically you do not need to call the /sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint for your SPA if its a first-party SPA.

Comment: Hey, after carefully rereading the solution several times and doing some tests, I now fully understand. Yes, that answer answers my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: btw I have a question, do you have EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful enabled in your Kernel.php? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/app/Http/Kernel.php#L42

Comment: @BernardWiesner Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated this issue further and found that the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` endpoint actually only returns a 204 empty content. You can check here:

https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/5a602d520474e103174900301d7b791e6d7cd953/src/Http/Controllers/CsrfCookieController.php#L12

```php
return new JsonResponse(null, 204);
```

And the comment in the file says:

> Return an empty response simply to trigger the storage of the CSRF cookie in the browser.

Actually you can call any GET API endpoint from your SPA and it will return the CSRF cookie. Basically you just need to have called a GET endpoint once before calling any POST endpoint, including the login endpoint, which should be POST.

The reason for this is that sanctum by default returns a CSRF cookie when you call a GET endpoint for SPAs (using same host or same sub-host).

So for most use cases out there you might not need to call the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` endpoint before login, because you might have already called a GET endpoint before that. However if the login, or any other POST endpoint is the first one you are calling, you first need to call the above GET endpoint just to trigger the storage of the CSRF cookie in the browser.

The docs are not so clear on this I am trying to submit a PR to clear this up.

Comment: I agree the docs are not clear on this. Submitting a PR would really help others in the future. Thanks for this.